# How to apply a loop to filter a dataset and then bind the outcome with other dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I am new at programming and bad at using loops in R. I'm facing a situation in which if I do not use a loop, I think I'm going to spend lots of time achieving my goal.

I have a big csv file in my working directory, that contains data related to 64 animal species (this csv is represented by the object "df2", created below). In the same directory, I have 64 smaller csv files, each one related to an animal species that is also present in the bigger csv. These 64 smaller files have the same number of columns (6), but different numbers of rows. I'll create some toy data to illustrate it and divide my question into four parts to make it as clear as I can.

```
library(tidyverse)

#Creating a df just to split it 

df <- data.frame(animal=c(c("dog", "DOG"),
                          rep("cat", 4),
                          "frog",
                          rep("bird", 7),
                          rep("snake", 5),
                          rep("lizard", 3),
                          c("cow","cOW","COW","coww"),
                          rep("worm",6),
                          "lion",
                          rep("shark",9)),
                 var1=rnorm(42),
                 var2=rnorm(42),
                 var3=rnorm(42),
                 var4=rnorm(42),
                 var5=rnorm(42)) 

#The following steps are just to make a reproducible example. I'm filtering the toy data just to save it as csv files and import them.

da1 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="dog" | animal=="DOG")
da2 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="cat")
da3 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="frog")
da4 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="bird")
da5 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="snake")
da6 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="lizard")
da7 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="cow" | animal=="cOW"|
           animal=="COW" | animal=="coww")
da8 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="worm")
da9 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="lion")
da10 <- df %>% 
  filter(animal=="shark")

readr::write_csv(da1, "da1.csv")
readr::write_csv(da2, "da2.csv")
readr::write_csv(da3, "da3.csv")
readr::write_csv(da4, "da4.csv")
readr::write_csv(da5, "da5.csv")
readr::write_csv(da6, "da6.csv")
readr::write_csv(da7, "da7.csv")
readr::write_csv(da8, "da8.csv")
readr::write_csv(da9, "da9.csv")
readr::write_csv(da10, "da10.csv")

#Those 10 csv files correspond to the 64 ones that I have in my directory
```

**Part 1:**
As you can see, I had to filter one species at a time. So, my first question is: how can I pass those filters and the "readr::write_csv" function inside of a loop so that I can do it all at once? (Instead of doing it individually). Note that some species such as "dog" and "cow" have several spellings. That's a problem I have to deal with since I downloaded my actual data from databases online and the files have such issues.

To load the small csv files I do the following:

```
library(rio)

data <- import_list(dir("path_to_directory", pattern = ".csv"), rbind = FALSE)
```

**Part 2**
Once I've imported them as above, they are stored in the object "data". This changes their order so that they are listed as da1, da10, da2, da3, da4, and so on, instead of sequentially as da1, da2, da3, da4, da5... What I want to do now is to reorder them from 1 to 10. After that, I would like to select the same three columns (animal, var1, var2) from each of the datasets. I was able to do that for each of the datasets individually:

```
ba1 <- data$da1 %>% 
  dplyr::select(animal, var1, var2)

ba2 <- data$da2 %>% 
  dplyr::select(animal, var1, var2)
.
.
.
```

Again, I would like to do it all at once using a loop or something like that.

**Part 3**
Once I've selected the columns and saved them in objects, I want to bind the resulting objects with subsets of the big csv file I cited above. Here are some toy data for it:

```
df2 <- data.frame(animal=c(rep("dog2", 2),
                          rep("cat2", 4),
                          "frog2",
                          rep("bird2", 7),
                          rep("snake2", 5),
                          rep("lizard2", 3),
                          rep("cow2",4),
                          rep("worm2",6),
                          "lion2",
                          rep("shark2",9)),
                 var1=rnorm(42),
                 var2=rnorm(42))

#This time all animals have the same spelling since I tabulated those data manually.
```

The subsets that I refer to are made by filtering this data frame by animal species. I was able to do that using dplyr::filter:

```
ca1 <- df2 %>% 
  filter(animal=="dog2")

ca2 <- df2 %>% 
  filter(animal=="cat2")
.
.
.
```

And so on until I've done it with all the animals. As my actual data contains several (64) animal species, filtering the df2 that way takes a lot of time, so I would like to do so using a faster way. I think a for loop can be useful, but I suck at this kind of programming and did not manage to write the code for it. Could anyone provide the code for it, please?

**Part 4**

Finally, once the species in the df2 are filtered, I want to use a loop to bind (rbind) the objects that refer to the same species, such as ba1 and ca1 in this example, and then save the objects as new csv files:

```
readr::write_csv(rbind(ba1, ca1), "ga1.csv")
readr::write_csv(rbind(ba2, ca2), "ga2.csv")
.
.
.
```

By doing that I should have 64 new csv files, containing a combination of the data of the 64 old ones and part of my big csv file. Could anyone help me? I would really appreciate it if you could answer my question stepwise.

I appreciate your time and your attention in reading all of this. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing. You refer to "da#", "a#", "ba#", and "c1" but only "da#" and "ba#" are actually defined in your code. Here is a start on what you seem to be trying to do. First creating the files you are using as an example:

```
animals <- split(df2, df2$animal)
fnames <- paste0("da", formatC(1:10, digits=2, width=2, flag="0"), ".csv")
invisible(lapply(1:10, function(x) write_csv(animals[[x]], fnames[x])))
dir(pattern=".csv")
#  [1] "da01.csv" "da02.csv" "da03.csv" "da04.csv" "da05.csv" "da06.csv" "da07.csv" "da08.csv" "da09.csv" "da10.csv"
```

First we split `df2` into the different kinds of animals and then use `lapply` to create 10 .csv files but label them so they will appear in the correct numeric order.

Since splitting a data frame is easy, why not combine all of the files into a single data frame (`alldata <- do.call(rbind, animals)`), extract the columns you want and then use `split` to separate them by animal type. You can then keep the list and extract the parts you want - usually the simpler approach if you plan to do similar analyses on all of them - or extract them as separate objects.

Comment: Consider directly running *animals* in lapply for `split` + `lapply` solution or better yet just call `by` (wrapper to `tapply`): `by(df2, df2$animal, myfunction)`

Comment: @dcarlson, I've updated my question to correct the issues you indicated and to make it clearer. Could you please check it out?

Comment: Given that the structure of all of the files is the same, create one data frame for the big file and all the smaller files first. If `allfiles` is the combined data frame, use `unique(allfiles$animal)` to identify misspelled animals and then use `gsub()` to replace the misspelled animals with the correct spelling. Save this file using `save()` so you will not have to clean the data again later. Then extract the columns you want, and finally use `split()` to create a list of data frames, one for each animal. Don't split the file until everything else is done.